# Openlayers 3 z-ordering of features

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a vector layer, which contains polygons and points loaded from GEOJSON source. It looks to me, points are always positioned above polygons regardless of their order in source GEOJSON file. See an example definition below. Is there a way, how to position points below polygons on the same layer?

The example:

Points are styled as white and red circle. Polygon is gray.

[image]

My GEOJSON looks like this (I even tried to reverse features order in the file):

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "radius": "1000"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                12.4,
                50.08333
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "radius": "800"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                12.4,
                50.08333
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
                [
                    12.4,
                    50.08333
                ],

...........
```

Comment: Did you try using zIndex in the style objects?

Comment: No, I tried renderOrder option for the layer. I'll try.

Comment: Great, it works, thanks a lot. If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zIndex in the style objects.